# How to create Empty array using for loop in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make one empty array using for loop, and for this I wrote below code, but it displays array elements like `1,2,3,4,5` in NSLog statements, but I want to display empty array like `("","","","","")`

Here is my code:

```
arrTemp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];   
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    [arrTemp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
}
NSLog(@"array detais is %@",arrTemp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following:

```
[arrTemp addObject:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift you can do the same in one line of code:

```
var arrTemp = Array(count: 5, repeatedValue: "")
```

Answer (score 0):

A perfectly correct answer has been provided by Alessandro.  However, I think understanding why your solution did not provide the required result would be beneficial to your learning.

In the line: 
 **[arrTemp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];**

you are adding a string with the %d format, which indicates an integer.
The integer is being provided by your loop: **for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)**
the first item added is a 0, then a 1,..4; 
By using empty quotes, you have the solution you are looking for.

**[arrTemp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];**

You are not using any formatter with your string, so the statement can be simplified into the answer provided by Alessandro

-:**[arrTemp addObject:@""];**